# Condensing X,Y by Y

Tags: python, zip

I have a set of data like this in the format x,y:

```
a = [([2,-2,0.29]), 0)([-2,0,1.9]), 2),([ 2,1,2.35]),3),([2, -3,2.96]), 3)
```

is there a way to condense by y so that I would get ([ 2,1,2.35]),([2, -3,2.96]) together? I would like to get them together so that I could find the max x and y of each of the two x's. As you can see, my x term is actually an x,y,z in itself.

*EDIT*
This is the code I have tried. I need a way to make it to where I don't have to code in the '3'.

```
import numpy as np
a = [([2, -2, 0.29], 0), ([-2, 0, 1.9], 2), ([2, 1, 2.35], 3), ([2, -3, 2.96], 3)]
b = [0,2,3,3,5,5,6,6,6,8,8,9,10,11,11,11,16,16,16,16,17,18,19,20,20,20,23,24,25,26,28]
cur = []
for x,y in a:
if y == 3:
    cur.append(x)
    b.remove(3)
```

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Have you tried writing some code to attempt it? What happened?

Comment: your parenthesis are not matched correctly... as such it is hard to understand what is being asked

Comment: Maybe `a = [([2, -2, 0.29], 0), ([-2, 0, 1.9], 2), ([2, 1, 2.35], 3), ([2, -3, 2.96], 3)]` is what you meant?

Comment: @Matt I attempted code, but I could only get one y value at a time to condense. In other words, I could get all of my 0's or all of my 2's to condense, but they go all the way to 28 in this particular case.

Comment: Let's see your code (please edit it into the question, not the comments!) so we can see your thought process, and so you can learn what part of your approach didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [1]: a = [([2, -2, 0.29], 0), ([-2, 0, 1.9], 2), ([2, 1, 2.35], 3), ([2, -3, 2.96], 3)]

In [2]: result={}

In [3]: for x in a:
   ...:     result.setdefault(x[1],[]).append(x[0])
   ...:     

In [4]: result[3]
Out[4]: [[2, 1, 2.35], [2, -3, 2.96]]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I guess I need to look more into dictionaries.

Comment: can you explain how this works more in detail? Or direct me to the documentation.

Comment: `setdefault` is used when you want to set `default` value for dict key. In above operation; i have set a empty `list` as a default value for that key and then perform `append` method on that `list` for each `x`.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm so clueless with this, I am referencing my books. Is there an easy way to get at the x (of the XYZ) of each of those x's? I'm thinking slicing, but I get the whole set of xyz's.

Comment: yes..  they are list and you have refer them with their index value. . for example if `result[3][0][-1]` or `result[3][0][2]` will give me `2.35`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to put them into a default dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_data = defaultdict()
for data_point in a:
 if data_point[1] in new_data:
   new_data[data_point[1]].append(data_point[0])
 else:
   new_data[data_point[1]] = [data_point[0]]
```

Then to get the max values for each part you can do

```
for item in new_data.items():
     print "For key: ",
     print item[0]
     print max([data[0] for data in item[1]])
     print max([data[1] for data in item[1]])
     print max([data[2] for data in item[1]])
     print "---------"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two solutions.

If you know that all groups of equal `y` values are adjacent to each other (for instance, because your list is sorted), you can use `itertools.groupby` to combine the adjacent values:

```
from itertools import groupby

def condense_on_y(lst):
    return [group[0][1], [x for x,y in group]
            for group in groupby(lst, lambda item: item[1])]
```

If your list might not be in order, then I think you'll need to put things in another data structure. Here's a solution using a `defaultdict` and `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def condense(lst):
    dct = defaultdict(list)
    for x, y in lst:
        values[y].append(x)

    return list(dct.items()) # list(...) wrapper not needed in Python 2
```